# How to create a circular gallery view / image switcher / image views...?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery, imageswitcher

I am having a requirement like want to have a cyclic gallery view shown as in the image.

[image: cylic]

Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with below code its not exactly what you want you have to modify some radians value and you are done

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/androcarousel.aspx

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i was not searching for animation stuff.?